# Angular2+: Call provider from a class (not component)

Tags: angular, ionic3

Let's say I have the following provider:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class ItemProvider {

    constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    }

    add(qtt: number) {
        // POST with http and returns a promise
    }

}
```

And the following class:

```
export class Item {
    private qtt: number;

    constructor(qtt: number) {
        this.qtt = qtt;
    }

    add() {
        this.qtt++;
        // TODO Call add() from ItemProvider
    }
}
```

How can I call `add()` from ItemProvider on my `add()` method which is in Item class? Or is it a bad way of thinking?

Just for you to know, an Item is created as `let item = new Item(1)` and the `add()` method is called from its view, such as:

```
<button (click)="item.add()"></button>
```

Comment: You can do that, but you must send the provider as a parameter of the Item class, in your example should be called like `let item = new Item(1, ItemProvider)`.

Comment: Hello @DiegoCardozo, thank you for your answer. I've tried and returns a `this.provider.add is not a function` error. Maybe I'm getting the provider wrong on my constructor. How can I get `ItemProvider` on Item class constructor? E.g.: `constructor(provider: ItemProvider){this.provider = provider}`?

Comment: Oh yeah @DiegoCardozo my bad passing the ItemProvider on the constructor. Worked as expected, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
@Injectable()
export class ItemProvider {

  add(qtt: number) {
    console.log(qtt)
    // POST with http and returns a promise
  }

}

    let item = new ItemProvider();
    item.add(1);
```

Comment: As there's no `@injectable()` for the Item class, it's not using dependency injection and this won't work.

Comment: You should use this in the Item class, you just need @Injectable in the ItemProvider

Comment: Thank you, everyone, for your feedback. As @KlaasCuvelier said, doesn't work, it returns `Cannot read property 'add' of undefined`. Is it a problem if I add ItemProvider on `let item = new (1, ItemProvider)`?

Comment: I think it's a bit dirty to pass on a reference of a service to a class instance, but I guess that's up to you.
I don't have enough context to help you much, but I think the Factory Pattern might be something to look in to; you could have a factory (injectable) that has a reference to your service (injectable) that creates new instances of `Item` while keeping everything in sync.

Comment: @KlaasCuvelier I was thinking the same. Thank you.

Comment: I edited my answear you can used like this, i think, but we dont have the conext of the usage